# getting an exception with hazelcast server and client

Tags: java, hazelcast

I launched the hazelcast server with my model classes that I do not recall seeing with the sample client - the error is copied below:

```
Couldn't connect to discovered master! tryCount: 50
```

Any suggestions on troubleshooting this would be great

Comment: are you using tcp or multicasting?  if multicasting, confirm whether you can use it on your server or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using multicasting, try switching over to tcp based connections.  If that does not help, try checking if there are more detailed exceptions (or perhaps add one from where the exception is being generated).

On linux, I believe you can check for multicasting permissions through **ifconfig eth0** - result should give you a value for multicasting.

Comment: Then probably multicast has been disabled. I only use it for playing around and demoing. But most production environments I know of, make use of TCP/IP discovery.